# Change default calendar AccessRights in Microsoft Office365's Exchange

Tags: exchange, mailbox, calendar, microsoft, office365

My goal is to change the Default mailbox Calendar AccessRights to be 'Reviewer' instead of 'AvailabilityOnly' for all newly created Office 365 users.

After searching online and studying Microsoft's docs, I have arrived the following command:

Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {Set-MailboxFolderPermission $_”:\calendar” -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer}

This command however only applies to current mailboxes, not ones that will be created in the future.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are wo methods four your reference:

1.You can create new mailboxes with changing default calendar permission via a script. Please review to the answer of the following thread:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/1229ed0f-1441-47a6-a6d2-14f6e0846892/default-calendar-change-to-shared

2.Navigate to Exchange Online admin center, then click on Sharing under Organization, you can change the Individual Sharing policy rule to meet your needs. Set up "Sharing with a specific domain" to match your Office365 domain, and then select the appropriate sharing option depending on what you want to do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The first method works fine, but it would require me to run the powershell script each time a new users has to be adderd.

 I tried the second method you described above, but annoyingly, even though I set the "All calendar appointment information, including time, subject, location and title" newly added users still have the 'AvailabilityOnly' default calendar permission.

Comment: The method I use for checking the calendar's sharing permission is the following command:

Get-MailboxFolderPermission user@domain.com:\calendar